# How to make POST request using NodeJS with Yahoo! Fantasy Sports API

Tags: javascript, http-post, yahoo-fantasysports-api

I'm trying to understand how to make a POST request to the [Yahoo! Fantasy Sports API](https://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/) from my Express server, but having trouble understanding how to approach this given the documentation is written with PHP. Developing locally, I can easily authenticate the user and send all the GET requests I need using the nifty [yahoo-fantasy api client](https://github.com/whatadewitt/yahoo-fantasy-sports-api) developed by @whatadewitt.

I've tried the following to no avail:

1. Using the `api` method on the main class of the yahoo-fantasy api client which ends up looking something like this on my Express server: `const response = await yf.api('POST', 'https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/league/${league_key}/transactions', options);`
2. Using axios to handle the https request
3. Google searching for potential solutions until my eyes started burning
4. Banging head against wall

Does anyone have any experience with using NodeJS to access Yahoo! Fantasy Sports API? I know this is pretty specific, but hoping someone has experienced this or something like it and can suggest some potential paths to consider.

Thanks!

---

[Edit in response to Luke Poirrier, who asked to see some code from my express index.js file]

There's not too much to it at the moment. Beyond requiring dependencies and going through oauth2.0 flow, I send the user to the `/oauth-complete` endpoint, which then begins making GET requests to get information about their game, league, team, etc. Truncated some code, but this should give you an idea of where I am:

```
app.get('/oauth-complete', async (req, res) => {
  // DELETED CODE THAT SETS REFRESH TOKEN IF NEEDED
  try {
    const sport = 'nfl';
    const { leagues } = (await yf.user.game_leagues(sport)).games[0];
    const { league_key } = leagues[0][0];
    const response = await yf.api('POST', `https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/league/${league_key}/transactions`);
    console.log('response :>> ', response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

And here is the error message I'm getting in my terminal:

```
{
  'xml:lang': 'en-us',
  'yahoo:uri': '/fantasy/v2/league/406.l.1087313/transactions?format=json',
  description: 'unsupported content type . only application/xml supported',
  detail: ''
}
```

Comment: If the question isn't actually about PHP, then you should remove that tag.

Comment: Could you possibly share the section of your server.js/index.js so that we can see exactly where you're at? Even just the section with the Yahoo Fantasy Sports API Set-up and Call would suffice.

Comment: @LukePoirrier - Thanks so much for the extremely quick response. I edited my question with code from index.js file to give you more context. I cut out some extraneous stuff, but it's really that line where I'm declaring response that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Update: I figured this out with the help of a friend and will be updating the post accordingly soon.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Sorry I was in class all day. My guess by the error was that you needed to add a request header with 'Content-type: application/xml'

Comment: Randomly came across this - you are doing a `POST` to the `transactions` resource.  You cannot use JSON to send data, they only accept XML in their `POST/PUT` queries (unless they've changed it) but you're also not even sending data in that request, just POSTing nothing.